# Parsing date with Joda API

Tags: java, parsing, jodatime

I have a string which contains a date "25 December 1985". How to parse it using Joda API?

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime("25 December 1985");
System.out.println(dt.getDayOfWeek());
```

I need to get a day of week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMMM YYYY").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTime dt = dtf.parseDateTime("25 December 1985");
System.out.println(dt.getDayOfWeek());
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "25 December 1985" is malformed at "December 1985"

Comment: What is your version of Joda lib?

Answer (score 1):

With reference to http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html

**getDayOfWeek()**

```
int iDoW = dt.getDayOfWeek();
```

where iDoW can take the values (from class DateTimeConstants)

```
public static final int MONDAY = 1;
public static final int TUESDAY = 2;
public static final int WEDNESDAY = 3;
public static final int THURSDAY = 4;
public static final int FRIDAY = 5;
public static final int SATURDAY = 6;
public static final int SUNDAY = 7;
```

or **dayOfWeek()**

```
DateTime.Property pDoW = dt.dayOfWeek();
String strST = pDoW.getAsShortText(); // returns "Mon", "Tue", etc.
String strT = pDoW.getAsText(); // returns "Monday", "Tuesday", etc.
```

Comment: Ok. But how to parse a string "25 December 1985? My example don't work. It throws an exeption.

Comment: Ah I see, you never said an exception was being thrown.