# Server time in local time

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I have problems with formatting server time. Server is on central time I guess. I need to format following string `2016-08-22T10:29:22` in default zone (*Central European Summer Time = GMT+2*). I tried with `Joda-Time` library, I need to get 12:29:22, but I only managed to get same date with +02:00 the end, with code like this:

```
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        DateTime dateTime = formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).parseDateTime(time);
```

Output of this code is: `2016-08-22T10:29:22.000+02:00`, when I try to  `dateTime.getHourOfDay();` - I getting 10 again.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2016-08-22T10:29:22 in default zone (Central European Summer Time = GMT+2).

10:29 in GMT+2 is 10:29 in GMT+2 and 8:29 in GMT, and the `2016-08-22T10:29:22` simply lacks information of timezone. So either make server return timezone or manually add it (i.e. append `Z`) prior converting.

Comment: You didn't get me, I need to format date 2016-08-22T10:29:22 in date in default time zone(mine is Central European Summer Time = GMT+2).

I got it now, can you help me with formatting manually and adding timezone?

Comment: [convert one time zone to another using joda time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21258214/1235698)

Comment: Done! Thank you. :)