# How to Convert Time Zone to UTC time zone using jorda time

Tags: java, android

Using this code

```
String twelveHourTime="06:00 PM";

public static DateTime convert12HourTimeTo24HourTime(String twelveHourTime) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter =
                DateTimeFormat.forPattern(AppConstants.TWELVE_HOUR_TIME_FORMAT);
        DateTime dateTime = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(twelveHourTime);
        return  new DateTime().withHourOfDay(dateTime.getHourOfDay())
                .withMinuteOfHour(dateTime.getMinuteOfHour());
    }
```

I am getting this date time:

```
String datetime=2017-09-15T18:00:23.153+05:30
```

Now I want to convert it to the US time zone.

Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258214/convert-one-time-zone-to-another-using-joda-time

Answer (score 0):

Use localDateTime:

```
DateTime dt = new LocalDateTime(timestamp.getTime()).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Comment: This i have tried  its not working same its giving @RTA1

Answer (score 0):

you can use it by using TimeZone and SimpleDateFormat :-

```
            TimeZone time = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(time);
            final Date startDate = cal.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat sdfAmerica = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
            sdfAmerica.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
            String sDateInAmerica = sdfAmerica.format(startDate);

            edDate.setText(sDateInAmerica);
```

Comment: where i will set  my datetime 2017-09-15T18:00:23.153+05:30 @Shubham Sejpal

Comment: i updated the code just now try it now by coping whole code again

Comment: OK wait let me check

Comment: 2017-09-15T18:00:23.153+05:30  where i will pass this can u please tell me

Comment: which country time does you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154508/discussion-between-adevelopment-and-shubham-sejpal).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat for conversion

```
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI");
  Date date = df.parse(datetime);
```

Comment: I have to Convert  2017-09-15T18:00:23.153+05:30 this US time format