# Calculate days between today and string of format yyyy/mm/dd in Java

Tags: java, string, date, jodatime

I have a String representing a date with format `yyyy/mm/dd` and want to calculate the number of days between that day and today. How is this done?

So It may be something like

```
String aDate = "1934/05/24"
```

Comment: I've look around joda Time, but can't find seem to find a method that calculates the day between two strings, just ReadableInstants which cannot be instantiated.

Comment: This will answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103064/java-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Comment: You are asking two different questions: (a) How to [parse strings into date-time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20098644/642706) objects, and (b) How to [calculate a span of time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3526485/642706). Both have been answered many times here on StackOverflow. You definitely should be using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package in Java 8, as the old bundled java.util.Date & .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Search for "joda parse" and "joda span". And search for Joda-Time's 3 span-of-time classes: Period, Duration, and Interval.

Comment: In java.time code: `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( LocalDate.parse( "1934/05/24".replace( "/" , "-" ) ) , LocalDate.now() )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way to do this -

1. Parse the date string to Date object using `SimpleDateFormat`.
2. Get the date difference between todays date and parsed date.

   `long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();//in milliseconds`
3. Now convert it to days, hours, minutes and seconds.

   - 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
   - 60 seconds = 1 minute
   - 60 minutes = 1 hour
   - 24 hours = 1 day

---

Other way  using joda date time

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/mm/dd");
DateTime dt1 = formatter.parseDateTime(aDate);
```

And

```
Duration duration = new Duration(dt1 , new DateTime());
System.out.println("Days "+duration.getStandardDays()+" Hours "+duration.getStandardHours()+" Minutes "+duration.getStandardMinutes());
```

Comment: I don't think that works with `long` since that only has 4 byte and 2^32 - 1000*60*60*24*365*(2014-1935) (approx) would not work here. `long long` should be used for 64 bit.

Comment: Maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). (2^63 -1)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I ignored that this is Java.

Answer (score 1):

The way to get the number of [days between two dates with Joda-Time](http://blog.joda.org/2006/11/daysdaysbetweentoday-christmas_4260.html) is to use `Days.daysBetween` but the `Days` class isn't part of the Java 8 `java.time` package.

Instead, in Java 8, you can do this:

```
public static long daysBetween(ChronoLocalDate first, ChronoLocalDate second) {
    return Math.abs(first.until(second, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
}
```

`ChronoLocalDate` is an interface implemented by `LocalDate`, so you can pass two `LocalDate`s to this method and get the difference between them in days. (However, there are [some caveats](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDate.html) (see ***Using LocalDate instead***) with using `ChronoLocalDate` in place of `LocalDate` in APIs. It might be better to just declare the parameters as `LocalDate`s.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the proper mask and convert it to Date and then use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object to calculate the days between (like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8912994/79230).